# Displaying line graph using data frame grouping

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, graph

I am learning data frames and trying out different graphs. I have a data set of video games and am trying to plot a graph which shows years on x axis, net sales on y axis and the graph has to be per video game genre. I have grouped the data but am facing issues displaying it. Below is what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.pyplot import hist
df = pd.read_csv('VideoGames.csv')
s = df.groupby(['Genre','Year_of_Release']).agg(sum)['Global_Sales']
print(s)
```

The data is grouped properly as shown below:

```
Genre     Year_of_Release
Action    1980.0               0.34
          1981.0              14.84
          1982.0               6.52
          1983.0               2.86
          1984.0               1.85
          1985.0               3.52
          1986.0              13.74
          1987.0               1.12
          1988.0               1.75
          1989.0               4.64
          1990.0               6.39
          1991.0               6.76
          1992.0               3.83
          1993.0               1.81
          1994.0               1.55
          1995.0               3.57
          1996.0              20.58
          1997.0              27.58
          1998.0              39.44
          1999.0              27.77
          2000.0              34.04
          2001.0              59.39
          2002.0              86.76
          2003.0              67.93
          2004.0              76.25
          2005.0              85.53
          2006.0              66.13
          2007.0             104.97
          2008.0             135.01
          2009.0             137.66
                              ...  
Sports    2013.0              41.23
          2014.0              45.10
          2015.0              40.90
          2016.0              23.53
Strategy  1991.0               0.94
          1992.0               0.37
          1993.0               0.81
          1994.0               3.56
          1995.0               6.51
          1996.0               5.61
          1997.0               7.71
          1998.0              13.46
          1999.0              18.45
          2000.0               8.52
          2001.0               7.55
          2002.0               5.56
          2003.0               7.99
          2004.0               7.16
          2005.0               5.31
          2006.0               4.22
          2007.0               9.26
          2008.0              11.55
          2009.0              12.36
          2010.0              13.77
          2011.0               8.84
          2012.0               3.27
          2013.0               6.09
          2014.0               0.99
          2015.0               1.84
          2016.0               1.15
Name: Global_Sales, dtype: float64
```

Please advise how i can plot the graphs for all the genre's in one diagram. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas plot, the index will be plotted as x axis and every column is plotted separately, so you just need to transform the series to a data frame with *Genre* as columns:

```
ax = s.unstack('Genre').plot(kind = "line")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Psidom ! it worked! Is there any way by which I can increase the size off the graph as you have above? Thanks again.

Comment: @GeraldBaretto, use `plot(..., figsize=(16,10))` parameter